# How to mapReduce Twitter entities with id list?

Tags: mongodb, twitter, mapreduce

**TL;DR**
My MapReduce isn't listing the _ids properly as values but creates multiple arrays. Any help?

**Full story**

I have a collection filled with tweets, including the entities. The portion of data that I'm interested in looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("h98342jdhs99191"),
    "text": "tweet text",
    "screen_name":"twittername",
    "entities":{
        media:[
            {
                "type":"photo",
                "media_url":"http://wwww.twitpic.com/HzKd99.jpg"
            },
            {
                "type":"photo",
                "media_url":"http://wwww.twitpic.com/HDK43.jpg"
            }           
        ]
    }
}
```

The key of the output should be the media_url. Because a url can be tweeted by more than one person I want the value to be an array containing the ids of tweeps. Something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "http://www.foto.com/kdh34a.jpg",
    "value":{
        { id:ObjectId("854737272343f8928") },
        { id:ObjectId("23137272378uie8928") },
        { id:ObjectId("85473727fdsd4x77665") },
        { id:ObjectId("8547372723dsd411zzc") }
    }
}
```

I've created the following MapReduce functions:

```
map = function(){
    if(!this.entities.media){
        return;
    }
    for(index in this.entities.media){
        emit(this.entities.media[index].media_url, {ids: [this._id]});
    }
}
reduce = function(key, values){
    var result = {};
    for(id in values){
        if(!values.indexOf(values[id])){
            Array.prototype.push.apply(result, values);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
db.tweets.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "media"});
```

When the media_url is unique the result is as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "http://wwww.twitpic.com/HzKd99.jpg",
    "value" : {
        "ids" : [ 
            ObjectId("528748b423421150010021fd")
        ]
    }
}
```

When it's not unique the results get weird:

```
{
    "_id" : "http://wwww.twitpic.com/HzKd99.jpg",
    "value" : {
        "0" : {
            "0" : {
                "ids" : [ 
                    ObjectId("528733ac234211500100004f")
                ]
            },


     "1" : {
            "ids" : [ 
                ObjectId("52873c772342115001000d8d")
            ]
        },
        "2" : {
            "ids" : [ 
                ObjectId("52873e142342115001001017")
            ]
        },
        "3" : {
            "ids" : [ 
                ObjectId("5287545a2342115001004fd3")
            ]
        },
        "length" : 4
    },
    "1" : {
        "ids" : [ 
            ObjectId("5287c43b2342115001010e53")
        ]
    },
    "length" : 2
}
}
```

What is causing this and how do I get one nice list of values?

Comment: Without testing, it's hard to be sure, but this: `var result = {};` in the reduce function and then the `push` is causing some of the problems. It should be declared as an array. `var result = [];`

Comment: That's how I started out, but this gives me the error: "exception: reduce -> multiple not supported yet". What problems are caused by the object declaration?

Comment: You're not really reducing much ... so I see why you're getting that error. You're getting the `"0", "1", etc...` field names because of the way you're using the result object.

Comment: How am I not reducing when I end up with what I am looking for: unique urls and a list of ids? It's just that the output is messy and not what I expected.

Comment: You're not aggregating the output -- like producing an average for example or a count of Url usage. From the `reduce` function, try `return { urls: result }` and change result back to an array object (`result = [];`)

Comment: Is it at all possible to mapreduce into what I'm looking for? Or should I look in a whole other direction?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41636/discussion-between-roland-and-wiredprairie)